# Image change on screen size CSS3

Tags: image, css, mobile

header.css contains the following

```
#logo { background: url(../Images/tarot/800.jpg); width:100%; 
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
#logo { background: url(../Images/tarot/400.jpg); width: 100%; }
}


@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1200px){
#logo { background: url(../Images/tarot/1000.jpg); width: 100%; }
}
```

the HTML page at present contains

```
<div class="container-fluid"> 
   <div class="logo"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not able make this work to change the image at 480 screen size. 
I do not know what content to put between the <div> tags to allow the CSS to function. Please advise. I have done hours of research and must be missing something. 

Thank you all.

Comment: I don't find a question, but there is a error in css and html. #logo targets <div id="logo"> not <div class="logo">. So either change the css to .logo or code to id="logo"

Comment: Thank you very much Veiko Jääger, The question should have been: How do I write a media query that will offer three different images when the screen size changes? 
The second was what image do I use as a place holder so that the phone gets the correct 480px image. 
I see that I was using the improper code for the <div> I will change that. 
Kind regards!